# Plotting a function with Exponential, Trigonometric functions

Tags: plotting

I didn't manage to plot the following function :

```
f[x_] := Exp[2*x] - Log[e + x]/(x^3 + Sin[x]*Cos[x])
Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

Can you help me to correct my code so that I can plot this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `E` instead of `e`.